# Youtube API - The request metadata specifies an invalid video description

Tags: php, youtube-api

I know this question is duplcated, but the phenomena is different.

I use Youtube API PHP to upload my videos. Unfortunately, its caught errors:

```
{
    "status": "fail",
    "mess": "Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 400: youtube.video, The request metadata specifies an invalid video description.)"
}
```

I checked the description. Use `mb_strlen()` return result less than 5000 characters.

```
$title = mb_substr($title, 0, 100);
$description = mb_substr($description , 0, 4999);
$tags = array_slice($tags, 0, 15);

$snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle($title);
$snippet->setDescription($description);
$snippet->setTags($tags);
$snippet->setCategoryId("22");

$status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "public";

$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);
```

Have some special characters exist: `<>`, `|`, `'` (single qoute), `()`, `?`, `"` (double quote). 
I researched about this error, but not any results :(

Comment: show your php code?

Comment: I included my code. Is it helpful?

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/32264-GoogleJsonResponseException-code-400-The-request-metadata-specifies-an-invali-d-video-description-.html). It might have something in your code that has a `<>` tag in the video description. Try to remove it and see if it works. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816251/adding-new-line-in-video-description-via-youtube-data-api-v3) might also help regarding special characters.

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove all `<` `>` characters from your description.

```php
$description = str_replace(['>', '<'], '', $description);
$snippet->setDescription($description);
```